# I am getting "Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed." while sending email using elasticemail host

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am getting "Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed." while sending email using elasticemail host. I tried everything but unable to rectify this error from the code. can someone please help me.

```
$email = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$password = '**********';
$to_id = 'contact@myemail.com';
$message = 'hello';
$subject = 'hello@12';


$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp25.elasticemail.com';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $email;
$mail->Password = $password;

 // Email Sending Details
 $mail->addAddress($to_id);
 $mail->Subject = $subject;
 $mail->msgHTML($message);

 // Success or Failure
 if (!$mail->send()) {
 $error = "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 echo '<p id="para">'.$error.'</p>';
 }
 else {
 echo '<p id="para">Message sent!</p>';
 }


 ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you rather use their PHP API to send the email? https://elasticemail.com/resources/api/send/

Comment: Yes @NickDuncan Thanks a lot... problem solved